# Launch Safari from iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, safari

I know that i can use the following code to launch **my own** url, but i want the user to continue their workflow after using my bookmarklet so therefore don't want to open a new tab and have them re-load the url i put into the `url` variable?

```
NSURL url* = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:""];
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to do? I don't really understand. It sounds like you might want to do something inside of a UIWebView in your app but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the above code doesn't make sense. The `url` variable is never used, and `openURL:` takes an `NSURL` and not a string. It would be worth re-jigging the code so it makes it more clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to open Safari without actually quitting your app and opening Safari. Or to somehow automatically return the user to your app from Safari once the URL you opened loads.

Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Kind of, i just want to LAUNCH the app without a url, not with one of mine - simply launch it

Comment: Ah. No, you can't do that either. Mostly because not every URL you might pass to -openURL: will open Safari. For example, "tel:" URLs open the phone app. http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can delegate a URL handler to your app. A smart example is shown here:
http://www.mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/

The scenario is:
- register URL handler
- open Safari as normal 
- get Safari to use your custom URL handler that should open your app (eg: myapp://)

Have a look at the way Flickr iPhone app does the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use 'about:blank' as the url?  That should just open Safari with a blank page.  I assume this would be similar to tapping the 'number' button in the bottom right then selecting 'new page'.